# cannot inject controller in routeprovider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

i'm still doing an execise in angularJS to improve my knowledge but now i'm exercizing about routes and i cannot get the controller attributes to work inside the routed template. I've read many tutorial and it should definetly work as it is now So i'm pasting the code snippet.

Javascript

```
angular.module('greetings', ['ngRoute'])
.service("Addcontent", function($http, $q){
     this.name = "Nome";
     this.familyName = "Cognome";
     me = this;
     me.tipi= [];
     this.tipi = me.tipi;
     this.selectedOption = this.tipi[0];
     this.getTipi = function() {
         var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get("http://localhost:8090/my-site/data.json").success(function(data) {
                  me.tipi = data;
                 me.selectedOption = me.tipi[0];
                 deferred.resolve( {options: me.tipi, selectedOption: me.selectedOption} );
             }).error(function(){
                 console.log("error");
             });
         return deferred.promise;
     };
}).controller("renameAddContentController", function($scope, $window, $http, Addcontent, $q, $routeParams, $route){
      this.name = Addcontent.name;
      console.log(this.name);
      this.familyName = Addcontent.familyName;
      consolelog(this.familyName);
      var ctrl = this;
        Addcontent.getTipi().then(function(data) {
            ctrl.tipi = data.options;
        });
        ctrl.selectedOption = $routeParams.showName;
        console.log(ctrl.selectedOption);
}).config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
  $routeProvider
    .when('/greeted/:showName',
     {
        controller:'controllers.renameAddContentController',
        controllerAs: 'rename',
        templateUrl:'/my-site/greeted.html'
     })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' })
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

As you can see there is a service, a controller and a route to be found. The template is very simple:

```
<h3>Greeting:</h3>
<span>
  {{rename.selectedOption}} {{rename.name}} {{rename.familyName}}
  <br/>
</span>
```

And the main html is simple as well:

```
  <a href="/my-site/greeted/{{greeting.selectedOption}}">Greet</a>
  <span ng-view>
    </span>
```

(greeting belongs to an other controller not included in this example)...

the error says that the controller is not a function, so it doesn't resolve the attributes mentioned in the template..

Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to remove the prefix `controllers.` at the route registering

Comment: It worked!, You can post it as an answer if you want!

Answer (score 0):

you controller name in :

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/greeted/:showName',
     {
        controller:'controllers.renameAddContentController',
        controllerAs: 'rename',
        templateUrl:'/my-site/greeted.html'
     })
```

should be only `renameAddContentController` as you defined it earlier, not `controllers.renameAddContentController`